# kivy remove_widget is not working

Tags: python, kivy

I wanted to make a kivy game with an stickman running around the screen, and as soon as you click on it, the stickman is removed.
I tried to remove the enemy widget by using Place.remove_widget(Enemy), but the Program crashed an I got this error message:

> TypeError: unbound method remove_widget() must be called with Place instance as first argument (got WidgetMetaclass instance instead)

Here is my source code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.animation import Animation

class Place(FloatLayout):
    pass
class Enemy(Widget):
    velocity = NumericProperty(1)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, 1/60.)
    def Update(self, *args):
        self.x -= self.velocity
        if self.x < 1:
            self.velocity = 0
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print 'es geht'
            self.velocity = 0
            Place.remove_widget(Enemy)


ROOT = Builder.load_string('''
Place:
    Button:
        text: 'Go Back'
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, 'y':0}
    Enemy:
        pos: 400, 100
<Enemy>:
    Image:
        pos: root.pos
        id: myimage
        source: 'enemy.png'

''')

class Caption(App):
    def build(self):
        return ROOT
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Caption().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Place.remove_widget(Enemy)
```

This is the problem - you aren't trying to remove an *instance* of the Enemy class from an *instance* of the Place class, but instead trying to remove the actual class itself from the other. This is the difference between `a = Place` and `a = Place()` - the former is the instructions for how to make a Place, the latter is an actual individual Place instance.

In this case you could probably do `self.parent.remove_widget(self)`; self.parent is the Place instance containing the Enemy instance.

Comment: I get the Error: 'Place' object has no attribute 'remove'

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo (now fixed), it should be remove_widget